# accessing a table where the column name is a reserved keyword

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am setting up Castle Active Record to access a legacy database on an Microsoft SQL Server.  The table in question has a column named **function**.  When I attampt to load a record it gives me this error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'function'

This error comes about because the SQL query nhibernate generates attempts to access the column named function, which happens to be a restricted keyword.  The fix is to wrap the column name in square braces ([function]) in the SQL statement.  Is it possible to tell nhibernate to do this in its autogenerated SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Castle ActiveRecord Table name conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752072/castle-activerecord-table-name-conflict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

http://quomon.com/question-How-do-I-handle-database-reserved-words-in-NHibernate-1148.aspx

Example where table is a reserved keyword:

```
<class name="User" table="[user]" lazy="false">
```

I think the same applies for column names. Wrap them in square braces.

Comment: the portable way to express this is using backticks, see duplicate question reference.

Comment: Not always. As you see in that question the user posted an answer that doesn't use backticks probably because using backticks would not work for him.